TypeError: is not a function in typescript class method calling
When I run the following typescript code
It throws the error

TypeError: error.sendResponse is not a function

Run the following code for reproducing it.
class AppError extends Error {
     statusCode: number;
     message: string;
     stacktrace?: any;

    constructor(statusCode: number, message: string, stacktrace?: any) {
        super(message);
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.stacktrace = stacktrace;
    }

    sendResponse() {
       console.log('This function is called');
       
    }
}

const error = new AppError(400,'not found');  
error.sendResponse()


Can you provide a [mcve]?

Yeah, I can't reproduce this so it presumably has something to do with your specific project. Please provide a [mre] so we can see what you're seeing when we do it. Otherwise you'll just get general suggestions like "have you tried checking error instanceof AppError"?

I have added the minimal reproducible code

It doesn't reproduce the problem, unfortunately. I get "This function is called" as expected.

I ran your codes, I get "This function is called"

Then I have done something wrong here. I am running the above code via npm like npm test, where test is defined in package.json file as "test": "ts-node ./src/a.ts".

It works for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tc4na4?file=src%2Fa.ts
